# vite + vue3 + ts When defining an event in the template, the error message is: "does not exist on type '{}'"

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vite

When defining an event in the template, the error message is: "does not exist on type '{}'"

The attribute 'useServiceDemo' does not exist on type '{}'.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a94TG.jpg)

version:
vue: 3.3.4
typescript: 5.2.0
vite: 4.4.11

The code is as follows：

```
<script setup lang="ts">
const {
  proxy: { $message, $service }
} = getCurrentInstance()

const useServiceDemo = async () => {
  const result = await $service.test.getBaseData({})

  console.log('result', result)
}

const useMessageDemo = () => {
  $message({
    message: 'this is a success message.',
    type: 'success'
  })

  watchEffect(() => {})
}
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <el-button type="primary" @click="useServiceDemo">ServiceDemo</el-button>
    <el-button type="primary" @click="useMessageDemo">MessageDemo</el-button>
  </div>
</template>
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "extends": "@tsconfig/node18/tsconfig.json",
  "include": ["env.d.ts", "src/**/*.ts", "src/**/*", "src/**/*.vue", "./components.d.ts"],
  "exclude": [],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"]
    },
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "strict": false,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowJs": true,
    "outDir": "./",
    "lib": ["esnext", "dom", "dom.iterable", "scripthost"]
  }
}
```

env.d.ts

```
/// <reference types="vite/client" />

declare module '*.vue' {
  import type { DefineComponent } from 'vue'
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any, @typescript-eslint/ban-types
  const component: DefineComponent<{}, {}, any>
  export default component
}
```

Comment: Not just methods, variables also have this problem

Comment: Hi @zwcong!
Did you try to remove every content from the body of the `useMessageDemo` and `useServiceDemo` functions (especially the watchEffect)?
I would remove every bits and pieces from the code step by step, and see when the error is gone.